# React Native Navigation, How do I navigate to another screen after pressing the button of an alert?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to Javascript and React Native and I'm confused why the following code doesn't navigate me to my other screen:

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName = "Home">
        <Stack.Screen name = "Home" component = {HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name = "Login" component = {LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name = "Register" component = {RegisterScreen}/>
        <Stack.Screen name = "Hub" component = {HubScreen}/>
        <Stack.Screen name = "NewList" component = {NewListScreen}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

function RegisterScreen({navigation}) {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.label}>Registration</Text>
      <TextInput 
        style={styles.input} 
        placeholder="Username"
        onChangeText={(text) => setUsername(text)}
      />
      <TextInput 
        style={styles.input} 
        placeholder="Password"
        onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
      />
      <Button
        title="Register"
        onPress = {() => Register(username, password)}
      />
    </View>
  )
}


function Register(username, password){
  Alert.alert("All Done!", "You have successfully registered.", {text: "OK", onPress: () => {navigation.navigate('Home')}})
}
```

I want function Register to show an alert where the user can press ok and for them to be redirected back to the home screen. The alert apears however pressing okay doesn't navigate back to the Home screen. From what I've read on the React Native Navigation docs function Register somehows needs access to navigation parameter but im confused on how to practically do that.

I tried using `useNavigation();` but I kept getting a hook call error.
I have also tried NavigationRef but with no success. I have also tried putting `Register` inside `RegisterScreen`. Also tried having `navigation` as a parameter of `Register`. No change in output.

Comment: You can seen it : https://100daysofcode.hoanguyenit.com/create-native-in-react-native.html or you config the code below 
you need import { Link ,useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
after then add  const navigation = useNavigation() in component and call  navigation.navigate('Home');

Comment: i've tried this but I get a hook call error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try put `Register` function inside `RegisterScreen`

edit:
The third prop of Alert.alert is an object array, i wonder why you didn't get an error there

```
Alert.alert("All Done!", "You have successfully registered.", [{text: "OK", onPress: () => {navigation.navigate('Home')}}])
```

Comment: Still the same result unfortunately.

Comment: It would be nice if you could share the code in the online editor

Comment: Not sure what you mean by online editor

Comment: Nevermind, Hussain already answered it

Comment: His solution doesnt work

Comment: Hey you may check the alert function as I just edited

Comment: lol thanks that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

you should define the `Register()` inside the `RegisterScreen` component like following..

```
function RegisterScreen({navigation}) {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

function Register(username, password){
  const user = new User(username, password);
  //const navigation = useNavigation();
  user_array.push(user)
  console.log(user_array[0].username)
  Alert.alert("All Done!", "You have successfully registered.", [{text: "OK", onPress: () => {navigation.navigate('Home')}}])
}

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.label}>Registration</Text>
      <TextInput 
        style={styles.input} 
        placeholder="Username"
        onChangeText={(text) => setUsername(text)}
      />
      <TextInput 
        style={styles.input} 
        placeholder="Password"
        onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
      />
      <Button
        title="Register"
        onPress = {() => Register(username, password)}
      />
    </View>
  )
}
```

or you can pass the navigation in Register function params like this

```
Register(username, password, navigation)

    function Register(username, password, navigation){
  const user = new User(username, password);
  user_array.push(user)
  console.log(user_array[0].username)
  Alert.alert("All Done!", "You have successfully registered.", [{text: "OK", onPress: () => {navigation.navigate('Home')}}])
}
```

and you can see `user_array` is not defined here
and what is the meaning of this line `const user = new User(username, password);`

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Ive tried this and I still get the same result, nothing happens after pressing okay on the alert. user_array and const user just have to do with my user class but it shouldnt make any effect on the problem. You can practically remove those lines

Comment: oh man, I got the issue
you have implemented the wrong syntex of Alert.alert()
I corrected it in answer please check it out.

Comment: third argument of Alert.alert() should be array.